# Backbone.Marionette Layout to consume the events triggered from a child view in one of it's regions

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

Using MarionetteJS v1.0.3.

I have a instance of a `Marionette.Layout` which has two regions.

The first region is a `CompositeView` on the left, the other region is a `ItemView` on the right.

The CompositeView renders multiple ItemViews.

The idea is, the user clicks on one of the items in the collection on the left, to display the selected record in full on the ItemView on the right.

How can the Layout at the top subscribe to the events in the chain: Layout > Region > CompositeView > ItemView

As the Layout at the top is the only one aware of the detailed region to the right, the event needs to be consumed here  all the way from the CompositeView where the click event would be triggered.  I know there are global events, but they are global, and there might be multiple Layouts running at once so their events would collide.

```
LeftListPanelView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: "#leftPanel",
    itemViewContainer: "ul",

    events: {
        "click li": "rowClicked"
    },

    rowClicked: function (e) {
        var itemid = $(e.currentTarget).data("itemid") * 1;
        var selectedItem = this.collection.get(itemid);

        if (selectedItem) {
            this.trigger("itemSelected", selectedItem);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the click event triggered by the list item should bubble all the way up the DOM hierarchy to the element associated with your Marionette Layout. Therefore, I think you could handle the event in the layout rather than in your LeftListPanelView using exactly the same code. Obviously that assumes the layout view has a reference to the collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use events. When a user clicks on an item trigger an event with `MyApp.trigger("item:clicked", myItemInstance)`. Then, in your layout, simply listen to the event with

```
MyApp.on("item:clicked", function(myItemInstance){
   // do stuff
});
```

Note you can also "automatically" have triggered events from an itemView bubble up to a collection/composite view (see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#itemview-event-bubbling-from-child-views)

You can see an example of using events to control your app's behavior here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js

That code is extracted from the book I'm writing on Marionette: https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction (free sample here: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf)

Comment: I would suggest to avoid global events whenever possible. This issue is more usually a problem with people not using controllers or not managing their views properly.

Comment: You're right, and I would also avoid application-level events where possible. But the question was about how one view could subscribe to events triggered in another view, hence my answer.

Comment: David, useful answer. In this case, do I need to do an `off`? I have experimented a little bit and it seems that not doing `off`, the layout remains in memory. Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, yes: you'll have to use `off` to remove the listener.

Comment: @DavidSulc Thank you. Is there any difference bewteen `App.trigger` and `App.vent.trigger`? I cannot find in documentation. P.S. I'm waiting for your new book. ;)

Comment: There's no difference: before you had to go through `vent`, now it's proxied if you call it directly on the app instance. New book is coming along nicely, should be releasable early 2014.

Comment: You can use `once` instead of `on` to avoid needing to call `off` manually.

Comment: @monokrome `once`, as the name implies, will only listen to a trigger one time. From the Backnone.js docs: `Handy for saying "the next time that X happens, do this".` The OP does not state that as a requirement. (If he's using Backbone.Marionette, he can use Backbone's `listenTo()`. When disposing of a view, Marionette will automatically unbind all of the listeners bound in that view)

Answer (score 10):

In short, you can bind to that event after showing your `CompositeView` on your `Layout` with:

```
yourLayout.region.currentView.on('item:clicked', yourFunction);
```

This is a much better solution than using global events. Global events work for the semantic reasoning of saying "this is event that is globally related to the state of my application" and (in my opinion) actually represent an anti-pattern that only needs used when project architecture has become a mess and needs refactoring.

The best approach with events is always to trigger an event from the object that it occured within, and to always watch events on the objects triggering them.

Comment: +1 and what I like from that one is that you do not need to pollute global scope with your current instance. Just run through the region tree you created, and grab the currentView member, its always the instance singleton.

Comment: Id like the events to trigger "automagically" like the collection view and composite view... i imagine it would work like this under the hood :)..